# nginx 正規表現でアクセスブロックしたい

Tags: nginx

特定のドメイン（サーバー）からのアクセスが多いです。

それをブロックしたいのですが、正規表現でクライアントホストを判定してブロックしていのです。

試しに下の設定をしてみましたがまったくもって機能しません。

```
if ($hostname ~* compute\.amazonaws\.com$) {
    return 403;
}
```

正規表現でクライアントホスト名を判別してアクセス拒否する設定はできますか？

Comment: `$hostname`はクライアント側のホスト名ですか？逆引きのコストを考えると名前で制限するのは難しい気がします。`$remote_addr`でIPベースで制限するのはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 確かに一軒一軒問い合わせないと行けないですね…
とにかくAWSのいろんなサーバーからアクセスが酷いのでIPだと大変そうです。
アクセスブロック以外で対処したいと思います。